# Why does a component has a separate injector, contrary to eagerly loaded module?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have been reading on the injectors in angular. After lots of reading, I got to know that during compilation phase the modules are merged and will be available in the root injector. But a component which is part of the module, gets a separate injector. Why does it has a separate injector

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-parent',
templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css'],
providers:[{ provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue:"From Component" }],
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) app_config: string) {
    //here app_config will be from component
}
}


@NgModule({
    declarations:[
        ParentComponent
    ]
providers:[{ provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue:"fromModule" }]
})
class AModule(){
    constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) app_config: string){
        //Here the value will be "from root"
    }
}

@NgModule({
imports:[AModule],
providers:[{ provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue:"fromRoot"  }]
})
class AppModule(){ }
```

I understand why the inject value in AModule is "fromroot", because of non-lazy loaded modules being merged at the compile time. But why is the behavior different at component level.  Thanks!

Comment: You're overriding the provider for the component, why is that shocking to you ?

Comment: `Whenever Angular creates a new instance of a component that has providers specified in @Component(), it also creates a new child injector for that instance. Similarly, when a new NgModule is lazy-loaded at run time, Angular can create an injector for it with its own providers.` https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injector-hierarchy-and-service-instances

Answer (score 0):

> But a component which is part of the module, gets a separate injector.
>   Why does it has a separate injector

Not if you don't specify the providers key in @Components decorator, it won't have it's own injector

It will get what to root injector provide.
Also, just to be clear, if my module does not provide that service, it will get what the root injector will provide, even if it's a lazy loaded module.

If it provides the same service then 
 1. if the module is lazy loaded, then it will have it's own instance of service (since it will have it's own child injector) (Angula likes child more thatn parent).
 2. If the module is eagerly loaded, then also no error -> same instance will be used, amongst the two modules.

Comment: The angular doc says for every dom element there is an ElementInjector , it is empty to begin with .

Comment: Yes, that's true. It will have the capability to provide.When you provide services in a component, that service is available via the ElementInjector at that component instance.
The point I was making is the resolution strategy used by Angular for DI.

The why part of the question would derive it's answer from the same IMO.

Comment: So does that mean that eagerly loaded module (other than root module) does NOT have its own injector?